# New to Javascript: How to debug what is changing text in <input> and <div> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I am debugging a complex web application and most of my experience is in OOP (such as Java) but not in JavaScript.  The application makes heavy use of jQuery and has lots of javascript pop-up dialogs and the like.

I have some  fields and also some  fields on one of the pages.  For some of them, data is not appearing correctly from the data source, in others, the raw data is there, but it needs to be formatted (i.e. phone number shows up as 1234567890 instead of (123) 456-7890 )

Unfortunately, the way this application works, these fields are not manipulated in code by the class or id name, so searching for either of these reveals nothing useful.

I have been learning how to use the JS debuggers in chrome, firefox, and ie.  I was optimistic when I found options in some of these browsers to set a breakpoint whenever a DOM element is modified.  Unfortunately, in the case of these tags, none of these breakpoints seem to fire when the text inside is modified.  (I set all types of DOM breakpoints that Chrome and FF offered me, still no luck.)

What steps would a professional JavaScript programmer take in order to find out how the text in these fields is being modified?  I would re-iterate, they are not being selected by use of the string literal ID or Class name.

Comment: your method of checking the browsers' debuggers is the one probably everyone else is also using, but you'll also need to know what to look for, obviously... though you'll have to add some code to your post, it's very difficult to help without it...

Comment: Are the inputs being created by script or are they in static HTML? If they are created by script, then it could modify them by reference to a variable, maybe that's why you can't find the string ID.

Comment: When I'm completely lost as to how something works, I start deleting code until it breaks. I start off with large blocks, then gradually narrow it down until I find the key components needed for something to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) bookmarklet to find which events are registered on which elements, but you cannot programmatically find which portions of the code will change a given element.